# Merging from commit to feature branch

Tags: git

On Monday morning I create a feature branch from what I think is a stable commit.  I work away and then I find out there are a few commits on the develope branch I need in my feature branch. It's not just one or two - in which case I'd consider cherry pick. It's 30 / 40, so I'd prefer to merge everything from develop into my feature branch.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just merge main branch (e.g. master) into my feature branch like this

```
### Ensure everything is commited
$ git add -A .
$ commit -m "My message"
```

Suppose your repo looks like this

```
*---*---*---*---*---*----<30-40 commits>-*---* (master)
             \
              \---*---*--<your work>--*---* (feature1)
```

Now merge master into my feature branch

```
$ git merge master

### Inspect the situation
$ gitk --all
```

You should see something like this

```
*---*---*---*---*---*----<30-40 commits>-*---* (master)
             \                                \
              \---*---*--<your work>--*---*----* (feature1)
```

Now the master branch wasn't changed at all but your feature branch is up-to-date. You can continue working on it now.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already pushed your feature branch, I'd just rebase it so that the branch diverges from the development branch at a point that already includes the new commits you need...